# Calculate row counts for certain records in NSArrayController with filterPredicate applied

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have a simple app that has an NSTableView bound to a core data-backed NSArrayController.

The application displays all of the records from the core data store in the table view.

I have some user settable filters defined which set the filter predicate on the NSArrayController. These do things like filter OUT records that have a flag set

I would like to have a dashboard that lists metadata about the records in the core data store, for example:

total number of records
number of records where field active = Y
number of records where field active = N
number of records where field updated = Y

I would like this information calculated on the contents of the store, not the visible content of the NSTableView.

The issue I have is that the arrangedObjects value of the NSArrayController is affected by the application of the filters, so things like total-number-of-records changes when the filters are turned on.

I've Googled a lot and looked through my various coding books but I can't work out how to calculate these values in a way that allows me to bind them to the value of an NSTextField in IB.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Regards

Darren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

In the end I found this to be the simplest solution:

I created additional NSArrayControllers in IB (one for each textfield), and bound the managedObjectContext of each one to the main moc.

I set the ACs to be in entity mode, then set the FetchPredicate of each to the relevant conditional.

In my UI I then bound the each textfield to the arrangedObjects @count of the relevant new AC.

Regards

Darren.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create another controller object that calculates these values directly from the Core Data stack and exposes them in a KVO-compliant manner?

Answer (score 0):

First subclass your controller, in this case NSArrayController. Second, create properties on the controller that represent the values you wish e.g:

@property (nonAtomic,retain) NSNumber *fieldActiveYes;
@property (nonAtomic,retain) NSNumber *fieldActiveNo;
@property (nonAtomic,retain) NSNumber *fieldChanged;

Next, create a custom getter for each property:

```
-(NSNumber *) fieldActiveYes{
    // ... perform a fetch by value on the field you wish
   //... set the fetch to return dictionaries only
   // ... use @sum collection operator to sum the fields
   return sum;
}
```

Bind the UI field's value to the controllers `fieldActiveYes` key. When the managedObjectContext changes, it should recalculate. If not, you might have to add some observing.